# Drawing A Line Graph, On Button Press Using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best and simplest way of creating a line graph using Javascript or JQuery? I tried  http://www.chartjs.org/ and http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/lines.html but nothing appeared.

I need it to appear when the button is pressed.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There are many client-side API's which offer charts.
I, personally, like working with [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). It is very simple, in some cases requires minimum setup and supports various data types as inputs.

You may find [demos & examples here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/).

All you have to do is:

1. Include a jQuery library (available [here](http://jquery.com/download/));
2. Include the HighCharts API files (JS & CSS), available [here](http://www.highcharts.com/download);
3. Create a placeholder for the chart (e.g. a DIV with the id "myLineChart");
4. Keep your data in a JavaScript object/array (note that there are several ways to provide data to the HighCharts, the best practice is a JSON object);
5. Call the HighCharts method, either when the page loads ($(document).ready) or upon another event of your choice. The following is a short example:

   ```
   $('#myLineChart').highcharts({
       chart: {
           type: 'line'
       },
       title: {
           text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
       },    
       xAxis: {
           categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
       },
       yAxis: {
           title: {
               text: 'Temperature (°C)'
           }
       },
       series: [{
           name: 'Tokyo',
           data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
       }, {
           name: 'London',
           data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
       }]
   ```

   });

In the example above, the data is provided as two arrays, each of them representing a series and will form a line-chart with 2 lines.

Note that HighCharts API Reference features full documentation on its options.

Hope it helps.